# How do you add data to a new row in a java swing table?

Tags: java, swing

I have created a new table row with the below code, however I am having trouble populating that row with data. How would one go about adding data to the new table row?

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable1.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[4];
```

Comment: Method [addRow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.lang.Object:A-) in class `DefaultTableModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got outside help - here's the solution for posterity;

```
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)
        this.jTable1.getModel();     
        Object[] row = new Object[4];
        row[0] = newUser;
        row[1] = newPass;
        row[2] = newDept;
        row[3] = newTel;

        model.addRow(row);
```

Note: Replace variables with what you want.